# Prove that $(A+BB^T)^{-1}B=A^{-1}B(I+B^TA^{-1}B)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-equations

> Prove that $$\left( A+BB^T \right)^{-1} B = A^{-1}B \left( I+B^TA^{-1}B \right)^{-1}$$ where $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and $B$ is an $n \times k$ matrix. Assume that all inverses exist.

I used the Sherman-Morrison identity , but I didn't get the exact form of this identity. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

$B(I+B^{T}A^{-1}B)=B+BB^{T}A^{-1}B=(A+
BB^{T}) (A^{-1}B)$. Now multiply on the left by $(A+BB^{T})^{-1}$ an don the right by $(I+B^{T}A^{-1}B)^{-1}$.

Comment: Perfect. Another method is employ Woodbury's matrix identity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) with $U = B$, $V = B^T$, $C = I$, right multiply the result by $B$ and factor a $A^{-1}B$ in the end on the left